# UISegmentedControl selectedIndex always showing 0

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

Just started learning iOS. I have created a UISegmentedControl programmatically and have initialized it with two items. I don't seem to understand why the selected index always shows 0.

Here is my code:

```swift
let items = ["Watchlist", "Favorites"]

var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {
        let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
        sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentChange), for: .valueChanged)
        return sc
    }    


// Action for segment change
@objc fileprivate func handleSegmentChange() {
        print(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of segmentedControl every time you access the variable.  Use lazy initialisation syntax: var segmentedControl:UISegmentedControl = {...} ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmented control is defined as a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259) which creates a new `UISegmentedControl` instance, with the `selectedSegmentIndex` value set to 0, every time it's accessed. Try using a property initialisation closure instead:

```swift
let segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentChange), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()
```